# Futronic fingerprint reader FS80H, 2 readers in the same PC, how can i differentiate them

Tags: java, fingerprint

I have Java application using Futronic FS80H.
Working successfully with one device.
But now i have 2 of them plugged in the same PC.
I want one to enroll, and the other must only read.
But i can't find a way to diferentiate them.
I'm using the SDK Worked Example for Windows, available at https://www.futronic-tech.com/download.php, and building my software upon that.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I got in touch with tech support via the email inquiry@futronic-tech.com.
Team futronic were very kind and supportive and helped me to accomplish the taks.
There's everything available in their dll api, and they sent me access to their ftp with Java code example to handle multiple FS80 readers plugged in the same PC.
I would like to thank team Futronic.